# Meaning of "copied" when used like this?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "the last element copied", does it refer to the last element for which a copy is made, or does it refer to the actual copy of some other element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an extremely pedantic point of view it would mean the last element for which a copy is made, but I would not go as far as saying that using it for the actual copy is wrong, and if I read "the last element copied" I would look for further context to clarify which of the two variants is intended.

**Rationale** (for the extremely pedantic point of view)

*Copied* here is an adjective made from the past participle of the verb *Copy*, and using the verb:

> I copied the element → The element is copied → the copied element.

Another way to look at it is that the object of the verb *Copy* in its transitive form always refer to that from which a copy is made, and never to the copy, and the past participle adjective is used to refer to an object of its original verb.